# CSS list style drop-down menu positioning

Tags: html, css, list, menu

---

My problem is that I just don't know how to position the drop-down children under their parent menu. I tried everything I can think of.
I have no idea how to make this work. Any ideas?

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ppltr/f9hmyokw/embedded/result/
And here is Satan:

```
.navi_l1 {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;}

    .navi_i1 {
        display: inline-block;}

        .navi_i1:hover ul {
            display: block;}

        .navi_i1:hover ul a {
            color: #fff!important;
        }

    .navi_l2 {
        margin-top: 15px;
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #333;}
    .navi_l2 a:hover {
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

        .navi_l2:after {
            bottom: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
            border-bottom-color: #333;
            border-width: 7px;
            margin-left: -7px;}
```

As you can see I can't make it work. This is how I feel right now: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-41v6n3Vaf5s/UeRN_XJ0keI/AAAAAAAAN2Y/YxIHhddGiaw/s1600/css.gif

help will be appreciated <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution for you.

`Try this way in this` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/o7mLc01m/)!

Looks like:

[image]